# Creating a datatable using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, visual-studio-2017

I am a C# noob so if I am doing something idiotic please let me know (this is my first time using it).

I am using visual studio 2017 to create a very simplistic front end for my companies database which previously was only held over many excel files. I am however having an issue creating a data table, what I have right now is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClientEmployer_FE
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Data.DataSet dtSet;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateTable();
        }

        private void CreateTable()
        {
            System.Data.DataTable clientTable = new DataTable("clientTable");
            DataColumn dtCol;
            DataRow myDataRow;

            //First Name Column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "firstName";
            dtCol.Caption = "First Name";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //Last Name Column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "lastName";
            dtCol.Caption = "Last Name";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //Disability Column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "disability";
            dtCol.Caption = "Disability";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //Skills Column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "skills";
            dtCol.Caption = "Relevant Skills";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //Goals Column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "goals";
            dtCol.Caption = "Job Goals";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //PT/FT column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "ptOrft";
            dtCol.Caption = "PT/FT";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //availibility column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "avail";
            dtCol.Caption = "Shift Availibility";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //location column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "location";
            dtCol.Caption = "Job Location";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //transport column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "transport";
            dtCol.Caption = "Transportation";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //accommodations column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "accom";
            dtCol.Caption = "Accommodations";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //bilingual column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "biling";
            dtCol.Caption = "Bilingual";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //OPP column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "opp";
            dtCol.Caption = "OPP Eligable";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //JD supports column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "jdSupp";
            dtCol.Caption = "JD Supports";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            //Notes column
            dtCol = new DataColumn();
            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol.ColumnName = "notes";
            dtCol.Caption = "Notes";
            dtCol.ReadOnly = false;
            dtCol.Unique = false;
            clientTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            dtSet = new DataSet("Clients");
            dtSet.Tables.Add(clientTable);

            //test row
            myDataRow = clientTable.NewRow();
            myDataRow["firstName"] = "John";
            myDataRow["lastName"] = "Snow";
            myDataRow["disability"] = "ASD";
            myDataRow["skills"] = "tactical thinking";
            myDataRow["goals"] = "office";
            myDataRow["ptOrft"] = "FT";
            myDataRow["avail"] = "always";
            myDataRow["location"] = "foo";
            myDataRow["transport"] = "car";
            myDataRow["accom"] = "N/A";
            myDataRow["biling"] = "yes";
            myDataRow["opp"] = "no";
            myDataRow["jdSupp"] = "no";
            myDataRow["notes"] = "is awesome";
            clientTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);


        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Right now when I navigate over to the page when this code is on I'm only greeted by a blank form. Is there a piece of code I'm missing to actually draw the table? The visual studio debugger isn't picking anything up so I know it's not just a syntax error.

Comment: Well, you are **creating** the datatable, you are not **showing** it anywhere. You need a UI: WinForms, WPF, etc

Comment: Thought it was something stupid like that. As I'm unsure about c# syntax, what is a good way to display it? @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: See [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview), you already solved the hard part. By the way, you don't need to set `ReadOnly = false` (default) nor `Unique = false` (default) and you can use `DataType = typeof(string)` as shortcut

Comment: This code is for the back end not the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a datatable which is not visible at UI front. If you are using winforms add a DataGridView to the main form and set its source to this datatable. Then you will have a UI for your datatable. 
You can drag-n-drop a DataGridView from Visual Studio Designer(suppose you name it 'mydatagridview'), then from code behind you can use

```
mydatagridview.DataSource = clientTable;
```

The columns you created will be reflected in the DataGridView.